# Vue - using v-model with vuex

Tags: vuejs2

I am building a search page and am having difficulty updating my computed property using v-model with the vuex store. I'm using [this wordpress theme](https://github.com/bucky355/vue-wordpress) built on Vue

In my data I have a main posts request that fetches the data from the wordpress rest api with 3 parameters that I want to be able to set using v-model and fetch posts accordingly.

```
postsRequest: {
  type: 'quote',
  params: {
    per_page: 50,
    search: null,
    authors: null,
    tags: null
 },
 showLoading: true
},
```

Then I am fetching a list of authors and tags to be able to get the id I need to use in the postsRequest params.

```
authorsRequest: {
   type: 'authors',
   params: {
     cq_per_page: 500,
   },
},
topicsRequest: {
  type: 'tags',
  params: {
    per_page: 100,
  },
},
```

Below are my computed properties and methods

```
computed: {
        authors () {
            return this.$store.getters.requestedItems(this.authorsRequest)
        },
        topics () {
            return this.$store.getters.requestedItems(this.topicsRequest)
        },
        posts() {
            return this.$store.getters.requestedItems(this.postsRequest)
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getAuthors() {
            return this.$store.dispatch('getItems', this.authorsRequest)
        },
        getTopics() {
            return this.$store.dispatch('getItems', this.topicsRequest)
        },
        getPosts() {
            return this.$store.dispatch('getItems', this.postsRequest)
        },
    },
    created() {
        this.getAuthors()
        this.getTopics()
        this.getPosts()
    },
```

I tried setting a watch on all three v-model properties. Looking in the vue developer tools, the watch does change the postsRequest.params on v-model changes but the posts remain the same.

```
watch: {
        "searchAuthor": function() {
            this.postsRequest.params.search = null
            this.postsRequest.params.authors = this.searchAuthor
            this.postsRequest.params.tags = null
            this.getPosts()
        },
        "searchTopic": function() {
            this.postsRequest.params.search = null
            this.postsRequest.params.authors = null
            this.postsRequest.params.tags = this.searchTopic
            this.getPosts()
        },
        "searchTerm": function() {
            this.postsRequest.params.search = this.searchTerm
            this.postsRequest.params.authors = null
            this.postsRequest.params.tags = null
            this.getPosts()
        }
    },
```

Template

```
<div class="advanced-search">
    <input type="text" 
       name="searchTerm"
       placeholder="Search title..." 
       tabindex="1"
       v-model="searchTerm">
    <select v-model="searchAuthor">
       <option value="">All</option>
       <option 
          v-for="author in authors"
          :value="author.id"
          :key="author.id">{{ author.name }}</option>
    </select>
    <select v-model="searchTopic">
       <option value="">All</option>
       <option 
          v-for="topic in topics"
          :value="topic.id"
          :key="topic.id">{{ topic.name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<section v-if="posts">
   <post-item
      v-for="post in posts"
      :key="post.id"
      :post="post"
      :postmeta=false
   />
</section>
```

I am learning as I go, any help is highly appreciated.

Edit (complete component code)

```
<template>
  <main class="site-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="advanced-search">
            <input type="text" 
                name="searchTerm"
                placeholder="Search title..." 
                tabindex="1"
                v-model="searchTerm">
            <select v-model="searchAuthor">
                <option value="">All</option>
                <option 
                    v-for="author in authors"
                    :value="author.id"
                    :key="author.id">{{ author.name }}</option>
            </select>
            <select v-model="searchTopic">
                <option value="">All</option>
                <option 
                    v-for="topic in topics"
                    :value="topic.id"
                    :key="topic.id">{{ topic.name }}</option>
            </select>

        </div>

        <section v-if="posts">
            <post-item
                v-for="post in posts"
                :key="post.id"
                :post="post"
                :postmeta=false
            />
        </section>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import PostItem from '@/components/template-parts/PostItem'

export default {
    name: 'Search',
    components: {
        PostItem,
    },
    props: {
        term: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            postsRequest: {
                type: 'quote',
                params: {
                    per_page: 50,
                    search: null,
                    authors: null,
                    tags: null
                },
                showLoading: true
            },
            authorsRequest: {
                type: 'authors',
                params: {
                    cq_per_page: 500,
                },

            },
            topicsRequest: {
                type: 'tags',
                params: {
                    per_page: 100,
                },
            },
            searchTerm: '',
            searchAuthor: '',
            searchTopic: ''
        }
    },
    watch: {
        "searchAuthor": function() {
            this.postsRequest.params.search = null
            this.postsRequest.params.authors = this.searchAuthor
            this.postsRequest.params.tags = null
            this.getPosts()
        },
        "searchTopic": function() {
            this.postsRequest.params.search = null
            this.postsRequest.params.authors = null
            this.postsRequest.params.tags = this.searchTopic
            this.getPosts()
        },
        "searchTerm": function() {
            this.postsRequest.params.search = this.searchTerm
            this.postsRequest.params.authors = null
            this.postsRequest.params.tags = null
            this.getPosts()
        }
    },
    computed: {
        authors () {
            return this.$store.getters.requestedItems(this.authorsRequest)
        },
        topics () {
            return this.$store.getters.requestedItems(this.topicsRequest)
        },
        posts() {
            return this.$store.getters.requestedItems(this.postsRequest)
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getAuthors() {
            return this.$store.dispatch('getItems', this.authorsRequest)
        },
        getTopics() {
            return this.$store.dispatch('getItems', this.topicsRequest)
        },
        getPosts() {
            return this.$store.dispatch('getItems', this.postsRequest)
        },
    },
    created() {
        this.getAuthors()
        this.getTopics()
        this.getPosts()
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: you are watching `searchAuthor` (and others) but i can't find them in your template ..please note that `watch` object properties must be named equivalently to the data you want to watch.

Comment: I have `<select v-model="searchAuthor">`. is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes , where is your`searchAuthor` ... with the code you included it's still `undefined`

Comment: I'm sorry i'm a bit confused with what you are asking. i have edited my question above with the whole code. I have searchAuthor defined in the data object.

Comment: great , now i can see it

Comment: Any idea why it isn't working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196933/discussion-between-dadboz-and-shubhra).

Comment: I'm trying to debug this and tried ```console.log(this.getPosts())``` in the watch property and i'm getting ```Promise {<pending>}```

Comment: Yep , like i said the problem is on the API that you are using not vue ... i saw your submitted issue on Github

Comment: I'm using the wordpress rest api. How do I resolve this? What do you suggest the issue is?

Comment: i suggest that we wait for the API devs to reply to your issue in Github and then we will see what's wrong